# how to not select somedata using xpath in webharvest

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, xquery, webharvest

I am using webharvest with xquery to get a data from a website.

I have the 2 xquery variables with the following data

`$text`:

```
<p> <strong>Psoria-Shield Inc.</strong> (<a href="http://www.psoria-shield.com/"></a><a href="/Tracker?data=gB90UgQvS9bs99znBBkklh-mudx4NTcPFIy_wiP7zUJ-qBXYABNid0GYgW4g7qVsjn3_dv2FPGzaYgKnhq_Ujg%3D%3D" target="_top">www.psoria-shield.com</a>) is a Tampa FL based company specializing in design, manufacturing, and distribution of medical devices to domestic and international
                  markets. PSI employs full-time engineering, production, sales staff, and manufactures within an ISO 13485 certified quality
                  system. PSI's flagship product, Psoria-Light&#174;, is FDA-cleared and CE marked and delivers targeted UV phototherapy for
                  the treatment of certain skin disorders. Psoria-Shield Inc., was acquired by Wellness Center USA Inc. ("WCUI") in August 2012,
                  and is now a wholly-owned subsidiary.
               </p> 
               <p> <strong>AminoFactory</strong> (<a href="http://www.aminofactory.com/"></a><a href="/Tracker?data=O0xbFRJiVuWDzRDq7SVwVR9xAPYLIGQyBw4mDziUrH4KB3DIYUasiO_O78eteJsv2doAGtg4kRhAqmnvkQ-9LA%3D%3D" target="_top">www.aminofactory.com</a>), a division of Wellness Center USA, Inc., is an online supplement store that markets and sells a wide range of high-quality
                  nutritional vitamins and supplements. By utilizing AminoFactory's online catalog, bodybuilders, athletes, and health conscious
                  consumers can choose and purchase the highest quality nutritional products from a wide array of offerings in just a few clicks.
               </p> 
                <pre>At Wellness Center Usa, Inc.
Tel: (847) 925-1885 <a href="/Tracker?data=rhuzXSqaPgDJ--ByIIMSm7wrtVUZmqiD7wl78d4gUHajkKceardtmAscrHABzvo360XXBJCWn_Rb_s-yPMVXTw_XJrSieD88bIXbE9snPn4%3D" target="_top">www.wellnescenterusa.com</a> Investor Relations Contact:
Arthur Douglas &amp; Associates, Inc.
Arthur Batson
Phone: 407-478-1120 <a href="/Tracker?data=9uKwR5tr9QwjFw830lvFTIWgz-s_eHaywZHwDl3el2RfYe5VuQZd_8sJU4J7HoFgOdyCn8br77RK60SIqLZkCy468cEKHpGUgE-nanwYfHo%3D" target="_top">www.arthurdouglasinc.com</a></pre> </span><span class="dt-green">
```

and `$contact`:

```
At Wellness Center Usa, Inc.
Tel: (847) 925-1885 <a href="/Tracker?data=rhuzXSqaPgDJ--ByIIMSm7wrtVUZmqiD7wl78d4gUHajkKceardtmAscrHABzvo360XXBJCWn_Rb_s-yPMVXTw_XJrSieD88bIXbE9snPn4%3D" target="_top">www.wellnescenterusa.com</a> Investor Relations Contact:
Arthur Douglas &amp; Associates, Inc.
Arthur Batson
Phone: 407-478-1120 <a href="/Tracker?data=9uKwR5tr9QwjFw830lvFTIWgz-s_eHaywZHwDl3el2RfYe5VuQZd_8sJU4J7HoFgOdyCn8br77RK60SIqLZkCy468cEKHpGUgE-nanwYfHo%3D" target="_top">www.arthurdouglasinc.com</a>
```

(This above text is just a example.)

What I want to so is remove the content of `$contact` from `$text` so far I have come up with the following code:

```
{
    for $x in $text
        return if(matches($contact, '')) then $x
            else if(matches($contact, $x)) then  '' else $x 
}
```

It is not working. I dont know where I am going wrong. Please let me know the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `matches(...)` for exact string comparison, it is made for regular expressions and you'd need to escape a bunch of special characters.

If the HTML subtree is the exact same, use this:

```
$text[not(deep-equal(., <pre>{ $contact }</pre>))]
```

If you only want to compare its contents, use `data(...)`:

```
$text[not(data(.) = string-join(data($contact)))]
```

But given the data you posted, you'd be fine just removing all `<pre/>` nodes:

```
$text[local-name() != 'pre']
```

Comment: return `$text[not(data(.) = data($contact))]` returns all the content in text with the $contact content elemenated?

Comment: Actually it returns all nodes which do not equal the node in $contact, but in the end, you're right.

Comment: the $contact actually has only data. there is no pre tag. I have edited in my answer. I am using "$text[not(data(.) = data($contact))]" and it does not remove the contact info.

Comment: `data($contact)` now returns multiple values, you need to `string-join(...)` them. I updates my answer, also the `deep-equal` version. The last alternative stays the same.

Comment: Given the information in your question all of those queries should work; the problem must be outside that code. We cannot help you if you do not post more information (especially code).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37662/discussion-between-codeman-and-jens-erat)